# How to call oracle stored procedure which include user-defined type in java?

Tags: java, oracle, stored-procedures, jdbc

### In Oracle DB:

I have the following stored procedure:

```
procedure getInfo ( p_ids IN IDS_TABLE, p_details OUT cursor )
```

Type `IDS_TABLE` is:

```
create or replace type IDS_TABLE as table of IDS    

create or replace type IDS as object ( id1 NUMBER, id2 NUMBER, id3 NUMBER )
```

How can I call getInfo in Java?

Comment: Similar to [Read an ARRAY from a STRUCT returned by a stored procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42853607/197733)

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Setting up a link between Oracle SQL objects and java objects manually is not a trivial task. In particular, arrays (or nested tables) of user-defined objects are more complex to pass from java to Oracle than arrays of standard datatypes. In other words, it is easier to call a procedure with signature:

```
(TABLE OF NUMBER, TABLE OF NUMBER, TABLE OF NUMBER)`
```

than a procedure whose signature is:

```
(TABLE OF (NUMBER, NUMBER, NUMBER))   <- your case
```

You can write a wrapper around your procedure to transform the second case into the first case.

---

That being said, it is by far not impossible to map your procedure. The following example is [largely inspired by a post by Tom Kyte](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:712625135727). Tom describes how to map a `TABLE OF NUMBER` using `oracle.sql.ARRAY`. In your case we will also have to use `oracle.sql.STRUCT` to map the `IDS` SQL object.

You may also want to browse the Oracle JDBC doc, in particular the chapter [Working with Oracle Object Types](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/java.102/b14355/oraoot.htm#g1104293).

First is a setup similar to yours:

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE IDS AS OBJECT ( id1 NUMBER, id2 NUMBER, id3 NUMBER );
  2  /
Type created

SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE IDS_TABLE AS TABLE OF IDS;
  2  /
Type created

SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE getInfo(p_ids IN IDS_TABLE) IS
  2  BEGIN
  3     FOR i IN 1 .. p_ids.COUNT LOOP
  4        dbms_output.put_line(p_ids(i).id1
  5                             || ',' || p_ids(i).id2
  6                             || ',' || p_ids(i).id3);
  7     END LOOP;
  8  END getInfo;
  9  /     
Procedure created
```

This is the java procedure:

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE
  2  AND COMPILE JAVA SOURCE NAMED "ArrayDemo"
  3  as
  4  import java.io.*;
  5  import java.sql.*;
  6  import oracle.sql.*;
  7  import oracle.jdbc.driver.*;
  8  
  9  public class ArrayDemo {
 10  
 11     public static void passArray() throws SQLException {
 12  
 13        Connection conn =
 14           new OracleDriver().defaultConnection();
 15  
 16  
 17        StructDescriptor itemDescriptor =
 18           StructDescriptor.createDescriptor("IDS",conn);
 19  
 20        Object[] itemAtributes = new Object[] {new Integer(1),
 21                                               new Integer(2),
 22                                               new Integer(3)};
 23        STRUCT itemObject1 = new STRUCT(itemDescriptor,conn,itemAtributes);
 24  
 25        itemAtributes = new Object[] {new Integer(4),
 26                                      new Integer(5),
 27                                      new Integer(6)};
 28        STRUCT itemObject2 = new STRUCT(itemDescriptor,conn,itemAtributes);
 29  
 30        STRUCT[] idsArray = {itemObject1,itemObject2};
 31  
 32        ArrayDescriptor descriptor =
 33           ArrayDescriptor.createDescriptor( "IDS_TABLE", conn );
 34  
 35        ARRAY array_to_pass =
 36           new ARRAY( descriptor, conn, idsArray );
 37  
 38        OraclePreparedStatement ps =
 39           (OraclePreparedStatement)conn.prepareStatement
 40           ( "begin getInfo(:x); end;" );
 41  
 42        ps.setARRAY( 1, array_to_pass );
 43        ps.execute();
 44  
 45     }
 46  }
 47  /
Java created
```

Let's call it:

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE
  2  PROCEDURE show_java_calling_plsql
  3  AS LANGUAGE JAVA
  4  NAME 'ArrayDemo.passArray()';
  5  /
Procedure created

SQL> exec show_java_calling_plsql ;
1,2,3
4,5,6

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed
```

Comment: If I was to change the table declaration for an associative array i.e. `create or replace type IDS_TABLE as table of IDS index by varchar2(50)` , what changes do I need to make to the java code?, I opened a question for this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12731742/how-to-call-a-procedure-with-associative-arrays-in-oracle-from-java

Comment: I am runnig the java code from eclipse. But the inputs are going null. My case is Table of objects. I opened a queston for this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20099905/call-stored-procedure-from-java-for-oracle-type-table

Comment: @Vincet Malgrat What if  create or replace type IDS as object ( id1 NUMBER, id2 NUMBER, id3 NUMBER ) again conatins an array like create or replace type IDS as object ( IDS_query IDS_QUERY_TYPE ) and again IDS_QUERY_TYPE is defined as CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE IDS_QUERY_TYPE AS TABLE OF varchar2(100) then how to define the struct? Help Please

Comment: @NikhilAgrawal You would use an Array to define `IDS_QUERY_TYPE`, then a Struct (with the preceding array as elements) to define `IDS`, then an Array (with the preceding Struct as elements) to define `IDS_TABLE`. See [this example on pastebin](https://pastebin.com/5sFXujRC). Note that the [`STRUCT` constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/JAJDB/oracle/sql/STRUCT.html) is deprecated in the newer versions of java, use [`Connection.createStruct`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html) instead if you have java 1.6 or above.

Comment: @VincentMalgrat Thanks very much. It worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using **Spring**, you may want to look at [Spring Data JDBC Extensions](https://projects.spring.io/spring-data-jdbc-ext), which provides a `SqlArrayValue` type.

Chapter [7.2.1 Setting ARRAY values using SqlArrayValue for an IN parameter](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jdbc/docs/1.2.1.RELEASE/reference/html/orcl.datatypes.html#orcl.datatypes.array) explains how to call procedures with array parameters.

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty good example. if you see **java.sql.SQLException: invalid name pattern:** still. Check the scope of the type that you declared in Oracle. I am using Oracle 11g and had to declare both Object of String Array and Table of Objects of my type in schema level. Spent some 3 hours and found that.

```
oracle.sql.StructDescriptor docObjDescriptor = StructDescriptor.createDescriptor("SSIADM.DOCUMENT_OBJECT",conn);
  String[] strArray = new String[] {"doc1","file1"};             
  oracle.sql.STRUCT DocObject1 = new STRUCT(docObjDescriptor,conn,strArray);

   strArray = new String[] {"doc2","file2"};
   oracle.sql.STRUCT DocObject2 = new STRUCT(docObjDescriptor,conn,strArray);

    oracle.sql.STRUCT[] docObjArray = {DocObject1,DocObject2};

    arrDesc = ArrayDescriptor.createDescriptor("DOCUMENT_TABLE", conn);
    oracle.sql.ARRAY array = new ARRAY(arrDesc, conn, docObjArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution I used lets Spring parse the object instead of having to manually create the STRUCT arrays.
Unfortunately, it still isn't environment independent.

Stored Proc DAO:

```
package ****.dao.storedProcedures;

import java.sql.Array;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Types;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import org.apache.commons.lang3.Validate;
import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.InitializingBean;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.SqlOutParameter;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.SqlParameter;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.SqlTypeValue;
import org.springframework.jdbc.object.StoredProcedure;

import ****.persistent.ComplexTypeObj;
import ****.persistent.InnerType;
import oracle.sql.ARRAY;
import oracle.sql.ArrayDescriptor;

public class SaveStoredProc extends StoredProcedure implements InitializingBean {

    public static final String IT_COMPLEX_TYPE = "it_complex_type";

    public SaveStoredProc() {
    }

    @Override
    public void afterPropertiesSet() {
        Validate.notNull(getJdbcTemplate());
        super.setFunction(true);
        super.declareParameter(new SqlOutParameter(RESULT, Types.NUMERIC));
        super.declareParameter(new SqlParameter(IT_COMPLEX_TYPE, Types.OTHER, ComplexTypeObj.ORACLE_OBJECT_NAME));
        compile();
    }

    public long execute(final ComplexTypeObj complexTypeObj) {
        Map<String, Object> inParameters = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        inParameters.put(IT_COMPLEX_TYPE, new ComplexSqlTypeValue(complexTypeObj));

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        Map<String, Object> resp = super.execute(inParameters);

        return ((Number)resp.get(RESULT)).longValue();
    }

    private static final class ComplexSqlTypeValue implements SqlTypeValue {
        private final Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(getClass());

        private final ComplexTypeObj complexTypeObj;

        public ComplexSqlTypeValue(ComplexTypeObj complexTypeObj) {
            this.complexTypeObj = complexTypeObj;
        }

        @Override
        public void setTypeValue(PreparedStatement ps, int paramIndex, int sqlType, String typeName) throws SQLException {
            Connection conn = ps.getConnection();
            try {
                conn = conn.unwrap(oracle.jdbc.OracleConnection.class);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                logger.debug("Could not unrap connection");
            }

            Map<String, Class<?>> typeMap = conn.getTypeMap();
            typeMap.put(typeName, ComplexTypeObj.class); //The name of the outer object type.
            typeMap.put(InnerType.ORACLE_OBJECT_NAME, InnerType.class); //The name of the inner object type.

            ArrayDescriptor des = ArrayDescriptor.createDescriptor(InnerType.ORACLE_LIST_NAME, conn); //The name of the inner list type.
            Array objArray = new ARRAY(des, conn, complexTypeObj.getInnerList().toArray());
            complexTypeObj.setInnerArray(objArray);

            ps.setObject(paramIndex, complexTypeObj);
        }
    }
}
```

Outer Type:

```
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.*;

public class OuterType extends BaseSQLData implements SQLData {

    public static final String ORACLE_OBJECT_NAME = "T_OUTER_TYPE";

    private List<InnerType> innerList;
    private Array innerArray;

    public OuterType() {
        this.innerList = new ArrayList<InnerType>();
    }

    public String getSQLTypeName() throws SQLException {
        return ORACLE_OBJECT_NAME;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeSQL(SQLOutput stream) throws SQLException {
        stream.writeArray(innerArray);
    }
```

Inner Type:

```
public final class InnerType extends BaseSQLData {
    public static final String ORACLE_OBJECT_NAME = "T_INNER_TYPE";
    public static final String ORACLE_LIST_NAME = "T_INNER_TYPE_LIST";

    private String valueA;
    private Long   valueB = 0;

    public String getSQLTypeName() throws SQLException {
        return ORACLE_OBJECT_NAME;
    }

    @Override
    public void readSQL(SQLInput stream, String typeName) throws SQLException {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("This class doesn't support read opperations.");
    }

    @Override
    public void writeSQL(SQLOutput stream) throws SQLException {
        stream.writeString(valueA);
        stream.writeBigDecimal(valueB == null ? null : new BigDecimal(valueB.toString()));
    }
```