# java.sql.SQLException: Fail to convert to internal representation

Tags: jpql

I'm trying execute following query:

```
String query = "select entity, entity.id from Site entity";
List resultList = entityManager.createQuery(query).getResultList();
```

And take exception:

```
[...]
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Fail to convert to internal representation
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:112)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:146)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:208)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.CharCommonAccessor.getLong(CharCommonAccessor.java:239)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleResultSetImpl.getLong(OracleResultSetImpl.java:552)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleResultSet.getLong(OracleResultSet.java:1575)
    at org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.WrappedResultSet.getLong(WrappedResultSet.java:724)
    at org.hibernate.type.LongType.get(LongType.java:28)
    at org.hibernate.type.NullableType.nullSafeGet(NullableType.java:163)
    at org.hibernate.type.NullableType.nullSafeGet(NullableType.java:154)
    at org.hibernate.type.ManyToOneType.hydrate(ManyToOneType.java:103)
    at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.nullSafeGet(EntityType.java:204)
    at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.getResultColumnOrRow(QueryLoader.java:338)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRowFromResultSet(Loader.java:606)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:701)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:236)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2220)
    ... 102 more
```

What am I doing wrong?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: There's a similar question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4268093/how-can-i-prevent-this-exception-java-sql-sqlexception-fail-to-convert-to-inte

Comment: In my case, the database column was varchar and the java variable was Integer instead of String. Changing to String worked.

Comment: In my case, the database column was varchar and the java variable was Long instead of String. Changing to String worked.....same as @Lucky

Comment: @Lucky Assume I am getting this error when trying to make some operation (creating a new snapshot) over a big Oracle Analytics Server catalog. Is there any way to find where the corrupt variable is?

Comment: @AlejandroBergasaAlonso How did you resolve the problem? The same happens to me with doing a bar export with Oracle Analytics Server.

Comment: @joseyluis It was a bit difficult to solve. In the end it was on one of the configuration files associated with the process of exporting the bar too. A driver path was incorrect and correcting it solved the issue. I will try to find the specific file to give you more info.

Answer (score 101):

Your data types are mismatched when you are retrieving the field values. Check your code and ensure that for each field that you are retrieving that the java object matches that type. For example, "retrieving a date into an int".

If you are doing a `select *` then it is possible a change in the fields of the table has happened causing this error to occur. Your SQL should only select the fields you specifically want in order to avoid this error.

Comment: thank you  +1 for the answer... why isnt it accepted?

Answer (score 15):

Check your Entity class. Use String instead of Long and float instead of double .

Answer (score 3):

Your data types are mismatched when you are retrieving the field values.

Also check how you store your enums, default is ORDINAL (numeric value stored in database), but STRING (name of enum stored in database) is also an option. Make sure the Entity in your code and the Model in your database are exactly the same.

I had an enum mismatch. It was set to default (ORDINAL) but the database model was expecting a string VARCHAR2(100char). Solution:
`@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)`

Comment: javax.persistence annotation to use is `@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)`

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and this is my solution. I had the following code:

```
se.GiftDescription = rs.getString(1);
se.GiftAmount = rs.getInt(2);
```

And I changed it to:

```
se.GiftDescription = rs.getString("DESCRIPTION");
se.GiftAmount = rs.getInt("AMOUNT");
```

And the problem was, after I restarted my PC, the column positions changed. That's why I got this error.

Answer (score 1):

Check with your bean class.
Column data type and bean datatype must be same.