# @ManyToOne Unidiretional does not works in Spring JPA DATA

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I am new to JPA , am using spring Data. I want to make a **ManyToOne UniDirectional** Relation.
My tables are **Countries** and **Region** and as expected the relation is Many countries belongs to one region. I try to do a fetchAll Data from **Country entity**, but it fails with the following error.

**Error**

```
2021-05-05 18:57:21.887  INFO 15512 --- [           main] com.spring.oe.ReferenceDataTest          : Started ReferenceDataTest in 5.917 seconds (JVM running for 7.155)
Hibernate: select country0_.country_id as country_id1_0_, country0_.country_name as country_name2_0_, country0_.region_id as region_id3_0_ from countries country0_
2021-05-05 18:57:22.304  WARN 15512 --- [           main] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 17059, SQLState: 99999
2021-05-05 18:57:22.304 ERROR 15512 --- [           main] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Fail to convert to internal representation
2021-05-05 18:57:22.341  INFO 15512 --- [extShutdownHook] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
```

**Region class**

```
@Entity 
@Table(name = "Regions")
public class Region {
  @Id
  @SequenceGenerator(sequenceName = "Region_seq", allocationSize = 1, name = "reg_seq")
  @GeneratedValue(generator = "reg_seq")
  private long regionId;
  private String regionName;

  // Getter Setters
  //......   }
```

**Country class**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Countries")
public class Country {
   @Id
   @SequenceGenerator(name = "country_seq", allocationSize = 1, sequenceName = "country_seq")
   @GeneratedValue(generator = "country_seq", strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
   private Long countryId;
   private String countryName;

   @ManyToOne
   @JoinColumn(name = "REGION_ID")
   private Region region;

   // Getter Setter
   //......}
```

**Repository**

```
@Repository
public interface CountryRepository extends CrudRepository<Country, Long> {}
```

**Test Case**

```
    @Test
    public void testFindAllCountries() {
      List<Country> countries = (List<Country>) countryRepository.findAll();
      assertNotNull(countries);
      assertTrue(countries.size()>0);
    }
```

**Error- Exception**

```
2021-05-05 18:57:21.887  INFO 15512 --- [           main] com.spring.oe.ReferenceDataTest          : Started ReferenceDataTest in 5.917 seconds (JVM running for 7.155)
Hibernate: select country0_.country_id as country_id1_0_, country0_.country_name as country_name2_0_, country0_.region_id as region_id3_0_ from countries country0_
2021-05-05 18:57:22.304  WARN 15512 --- [           main] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 17059, SQLState: 99999
2021-05-05 18:57:22.304 ERROR 15512 --- [           main] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Fail to convert to internal representation
2021-05-05 18:57:22.341  INFO 15512 --- [extShutdownHook] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
```

**Stack Trace**

```
org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: could not execute query; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute query
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:331)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:233)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:551)
at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:61)
at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:242)
at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:152)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:174)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:215)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy79.findAll(Unknown Source)
at com.spring.oe.ReferenceDataTest.testFindAllCountries(ReferenceDataTest.java:58)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:688)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:60)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$ValidatingInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:131)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.intercept(TimeoutExtension.java:149)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestableMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:140)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:84)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker$ReflectiveInterceptorCall.lambda$ofVoidMethod$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:115)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.lambda$invoke$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:105)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$InterceptedInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:106)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:64)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.chainAndInvoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:45)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.invoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:37)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:104)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:98)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestMethod$6(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:210)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeTestMethod(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:206)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:131)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:65)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:139)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:129)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:127)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:126)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:84)
at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1249)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:143)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:129)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:127)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:126)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:84)
at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1249)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:143)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:129)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:127)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:126)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:84)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:32)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:51)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:229)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.lambda$execute$6(DefaultLauncher.java:197)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.withInterceptedStreams(DefaultLauncher.java:211)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:191)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:137)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit5.runner.JUnit5TestReference.run(JUnit5TestReference.java:89)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:41)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:541)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:763)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:463)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:209)
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute query
at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:47)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:113)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2852)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2831)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2663)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2658)
at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:506)
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:400)
at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:219)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1414)
at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.doList(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1625)
at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1593)
at org.hibernate.query.Query.getResultList(Query.java:165)
at org.hibernate.query.criteria.internal.compile.CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.getResultList(CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.java:76)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.findAll(SimpleJpaRepository.java:356)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.findAll(SimpleJpaRepository.java:78)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker$RepositoryFragmentMethodInvoker.lambda$new$0(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:289)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.doInvoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:137)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.invoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:121)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition$RepositoryFragments.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:524)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:285)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$ImplementationMethodExecutionInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:531)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:156)
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:131)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:123)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:388)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:137)
... 73 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Fail to convert to internal representation
at oracle.jdbc.driver.CharCommonAccessor.getLong(CharCommonAccessor.java:256)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CCharAccessor.getLong(T4CCharAccessor.java:546)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.GeneratedStatement.getLong(GeneratedStatement.java:208)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.GeneratedScrollableResultSet.getLong(GeneratedScrollableResultSet.java:261)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.GeneratedResultSet.getLong(GeneratedResultSet.java:560)
at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyResultSet.getLong(HikariProxyResultSet.java)
at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BigIntTypeDescriptor$2.doExtract(BigIntTypeDescriptor.java:63)
at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor.extract(BasicExtractor.java:47)
at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:257)
at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:253)
at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:243)
at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.hydrate(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:329)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.extractKeysFromResultSet(Loader.java:803)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRowFromResultSet(Loader.java:727)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRowsFromResultSet(Loader.java:1039)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.processResultSet(Loader.java:990)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:959)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:349)
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2849)
... 105 more
```

What is causing this issue? What is mean by **Fail to convert to internal representation** ?
How to overcome this?

Comment: Do you get a stacktrace?

Comment: "Many countries belongs to one region" I think you flipped the two entities `Region` and `Country` in this definition. Or you missnamed the entity COUNTY.

Comment: Define the referenced coumn name: `@JoinColumn( name = "Region_ID"; referencedColumnName = "regionId" )`.

Comment: @SimonMartinelli - stack tack has been added for your reference.

Comment: @TheBitman - It did not work.

Comment: Another gues: don't insist to `GenerationType.SEQUENCE`. Instead use `GenerationType.AUTO`. Maybe your RBDMS does not support sequences.

Comment: I am using oracle as my backend. The sequence is not an issue. I have tested it with Region entity. All the CRUD operations on the Region was working fine. The problem started only after I introduced Country with @ManyToOne annotation. I am strongly doubting on the association part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem must be related to **Fail to convert to internal representation**. You must be making some mistake in the mapping between your entity and DB table. Refer the following link [java.sql.SQLException: Fail to convert to internal representation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963472/java-sql-sqlexception-fail-to-convert-to-internal-representation)

Comment: I downloaded OT schema from net and used it for my study.
In Country entity, I kept the **countryId** as Long but in the DB it was CHAR(1). That is the problem.
Once I corrected my Country.class with countryid as String it worked fine. Tested both unidirectional and Bidirectional. Its working.