# Call Oracle object-oriented PL/SQL member procedures from JDBC

Tags: oracle, oop, stored-procedures, jdbc, plsql

In object-oriented PL/SQL, I can add member procedures and functions to types. An example is given here:

```
create type foo_type as object (
  foo number,

  member procedure proc(p in number),
  member function  func(p in number) return number
);

create type body foo_type as 
  member procedure proc(p in number) is begin
    foo := p*2;
  end proc;

  member function func(p in number) return number is begin
    return foo/p;
  end func;
end;
```

From: http://www.adp-gmbh.ch/ora/plsql/oo/member.html

In PL/SQL, I can then call these member procedures/functions like this:

```
declare
    x foo_type;
begin
    x := foo_type(5);
    x.proc(10);
    dbms_output.put_line(x.func(2));
end;
```

How can I do it with JDBC's CallableStatement? I can't seem to find this in the documentation easily.

**NOTE**: This is one possibility, inlining the type constructor:

```
CallableStatement call = c.prepareCall(
    " { ? = call foo_type(5).func(2) } ");
```

But what I'm looking for is something like this (using `java.sql.SQLData` as a parameter):

```
CallableStatement call = c.prepareCall(
    " { ? = call ?.func(2) } ");
```

Also, member functions, procedures may modify the object. How can I get the modified object back in Java?

Comment: Is the core of your question really "How to call a member function"? Or is it rather "How to pass an object as a parameter"?

Comment: @Codo: The core is how to retrieve member function results (example answer given by Vincent Malgrat), and how to retrieve the potentially modified object itself

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `jdbc` you can parse and execute PL/SQL blocks with `out` variables. You could prepare a callable statement such as:

```
declare
    x foo_type;
begin
    x := foo_type(5);
    x.proc(10);
    ? := x.func(2);
end;
```

Then you can use [CallableStatement.registerOutParameter](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/sql/CallableStatement.html#registerOutParameter%28int,%20int%29) and after the statement has been executed, use the appropriate `get` function to retrieve the value.

You can access directly a `FOO_TYPE` type directly in java, but do you really want to do this? See below for a working example:

```
SQL> create or replace and compile java source named "TestOutParam" as
  2  import java.sql.*;
  3  import oracle.sql.*;
  4  import oracle.jdbc.driver.*;
  5  
  6  public class TestOutParam {
  7  
  8     public static int get() throws SQLException {
  9  
 10        Connection conn =
 11           new OracleDriver().defaultConnection();
 12  
 13        StructDescriptor itemDescriptor =
 14           StructDescriptor.createDescriptor("FOO_TYPE",conn);
 15  
 16        OracleCallableStatement call =
 17           (OracleCallableStatement) conn.prepareCall("declare\n"
 18              + "    x foo_type;\n"
 19              + "begin\n"
 20              + "    x := foo_type(5);\n"
 21              + "    x.proc(10);\n"
 22              + "    ? := x;\n"
 23              + "end;\n");
 24  
 25        call.registerOutParameter(1, OracleTypes.STRUCT, "FOO_TYPE");
 26  
 27        call.execute();
 28  
 29        STRUCT myObj = call.getSTRUCT(1);
 30  
 31        Datum[] myData = myObj.getOracleAttributes();
 32  
 33        return myData[0].intValue();
 34  
 35     }
 36  }
 37  /
```

This is a test class to show how you can use the method `registerOutParameter` on an SQL object, let's call it:

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE
  2  FUNCTION show_TestOutParam RETURN NUMBER
  3  AS LANGUAGE JAVA
  4  NAME 'TestOutParam.get() return java.lang.int';
  5  /

Function created

SQL> select show_testoutparam from dual;

SHOW_TESTOUTPARAM
-----------------
               20
```

Comment: Duh. I didn't think of actually passing PL/SQL to the database, instead of the JDBC escape syntax... Do you have any ideas about how `x` itself could be returned from the PL/SQL block? In this example, `x` is not modified by the procedures/functions. But it may be. So when calling `x.func(2)` I'd like to have both the function result as in your example *and* the updated value of `x`, as `java.sql.SQLData`...

Comment: You can retrieve SQL objects from PL/SQL directly into java STRUCT (example [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3626061/how-to-call-oracle-stored-procedure-which-include-user-defined-type-in-java)) However, I always find it is a bit convoluted: see my updated answer.

Comment: Awesome! Yes, I do want to do this. This will be used mainly in my [database abstraction library](http://www.jooq.org). You might've seen it, since you've answered my questions before :-). The goal will be to create a mapping between UDT's and Java classes. This already exists, but only for the data a UDT can contain. Generating Java source code for member functions and procedures is even more interesting, as this will make interactions between Java and PL/SQL very easy for client code, as they don't have to mess with this kind of JDBC tricks. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Thanks. With what I have already and your input, it won't be very difficult anymore :)