# how to call oracle's object type member procedure from c#

Tags: c#, oracle

*I know how to call oracle stored procedure from c#*.
Now i want to call a **member procedure of an object type**.

e.g

```
create type address as object (
   line1 varchar2(50),
   city varchar2(50),
   member procedure insert_address(line1 varchar2, city varchar2)
)
/

create table address_table of address;

create type body address as
   member procedure insert_address(line1 varchar2, city varchar2) is
   begin
       insert into address_table values (line1, city);
       commit;
   end insert_address;
end;
/
```

now, i want to call the procedure insert_address  [***not a stored procedure!***]
How can i do it?

Comment: guys you are giving me a solution for calling stored procedures. I know that, but I am looking for how to call member procedure of an object from c#.

Comment: Voted to reopen since we have apparently identified the wrong duplicate. Although you might want to check [this related question for JDBC](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7137274/call-oracle-object-oriented-pl-sql-member-procedures-from-jdbc) that approaches the problem from a different angle. It might give you ideas.