# Java List to Oracle TABLE of Object type

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, jdbc, plsql, stored-functions

I have created the following types and function and I wish to call this using JDBC.

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE studenttype AS OBJECT (
  2   sid  VARCHAR2(10 BYTE),
  3   sname  VARCHAR2(50 BYTE)
  4  );
  5  /

Type created.


SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE studentlist AS TABLE OF studenttype;
  2  /

Type created.



SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION addstudents(students studentlist) RETURN NUMBER IS
  2  
  3  BEGIN
  4  
  5   FOR counter IN students.FIRST..students.LAST
  6   LOOP
  7    dbms_output.put_line(students(counter).sid);
  8   END LOOP;
  9     
 10   RETURN 1;
 11     
 12   EXCEPTION
 13   WHEN OTHERS THEN
 14    RETURN 0;
 15  
 16  END addstudents;
 17  /

Function created.
```

I have a class called Student in Java that has sid, sname fields.
How do I set the input parameter of this function in Java?

Comment: See [How to call oracle stored procedure which include user-defined type in java?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3626061/119634)

Comment: Have you solved this issue?

Comment: Have you solved this issue? I'm having the same problem, when it comes to tables of ojects (plain objects are fine).

Answer (score 0):

You need to use STRUCT class, and Map it to your types.

Here is the documentation:
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/java.920/a96654/oraoot.htm