# Jdbc utility for calling procedure in oracle

Tags: java, oracle, stored-procedures, jdbc, utilities

I have complex procedures in oracle package with complex in/out parameters. I will show one of the my procedures in following :

```
 PROCEDURE Authorize(PO_ErrorCode         OUT NUMBER,
                     PO_ErrorText         OUT VARCHAR2,
                     PI_Count             IN NUMBER,
                     PI_Setting           IN Setting,
                     PI_InputData         IN InputData,
                     PO_PreData           OUT InputData);
```

and will show two structures `Setting` and `InputData` in following:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE Setting as object( ProviderType  NUMBER
                                          SwitchCode    NUMBER)

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE Input_Data Is Table Of MainInputData;

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE MainInputData as object( itemId            NUMBER,
                                                itemValue         NVARCHAR2(150),
                                                itemEncyptd       NUMBER,
                                                itemEncryptKey    RAW(16));
```

with above description I have several structure contain : `Type`, `Array`, `Array of Type` and `Array of Primitive`.

I call this function by `jdbc` and oracle driver and related classes such as `STRUCT`& `ARRAY` but generated a lot of and complex code for this goal.

My question is : Is there utility or framework for do this task by simple code?
I know `spring` has a jdbc utility but I haven't experience with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use spring utility.

There is a class `StoredProcedure` where can you declare all your input and output parameters and their types inside the constructor using `sqlOutParameter` and `sqlInParameter`.

In your case there are 3 input parameters, to pass this you can overwrite `execute`  method with 3 arguments and call

`super.execute(a,b,c)`

This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3626061/how-to-call-oracle-stored-procedure-which-include-user-defined-type-in-java) will be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

We have internal utility which does exactly what you need. It generates:

- JPA entities based on `Oracle Object Type`s and extended with `eclipselink` specific annotations.
- Java interfaces reflecting PL/SQL package.

In the runtime eclipselink translates the entity instances into `java.sql.Struct` instances, and call to generated java interface is intercepted by our runtime which dynamically invokes PL/SQL procedures and functions. It also supports IN/OUT parameters and allows to expose PL/SQL packages as webservices. It eases our development where we have lots of hierarchical Oracle Object Types. I wish it was publicly available. If your are interested in the tool, please contact me.

You can also use Oracle's [jpublisher](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B13789_01/java.101/b10983/intro.htm) for this purpose: