# Call stored procedure from java for Oracle type TABLE

Tags: java, oracle, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure in Oracle like below.

```
create or replace TYPE T_EMP_OBJ AS OBJECT (Name varchar2(20), Age CHAR(3 CHAR));

create or replace type T_EMP_REC as table of T_EMP_OBJ;

create or replace PROCEDURE P_EMP (I_NAV_REC IN T_INAV_REC, p_out OUT MY_TYPES_PKG.REFCURSOR) 
AS  ... 
END P_EMP;
```

I am calling that procedure from java. My code is,

```
StructDescriptor structDesc = new StructDescriptor("T_EMP_OBJ", oracleConnection);
ArrayDescriptor arrayDesc2 = new ArrayDescriptor("T_EMP_REC", oracleConnection);
    Object[] objType = new Object[2];
    objType[0] = new String("AAA");
    objType[1] = new String("25");
    STRUCT struct = new STRUCT(structDesc, oracleConnection, objType);
    STRUCT[] structs = new STRUCT[1];
    structs[0] = struct;
    oracle.sql.ARRAY array = new oracle.sql.ARRAY(arrayDesc2, oracleConnection, structs);
    OracleCallableStatement statement = (OracleCallableStatement) oracleConnection.prepareCall("CALL P_EMP(?,?)");
    statement.setArray(1, array);
    statement.registerOutParameter(2, oracle.jdbc.OracleTypes.CURSOR);
    statement.execute();
    ResultSet results = ((OracleCallableStatement) statement).getCursor(2);
    while (results.next()) {
         logger.info("NAME==>"+results.getString(1));
         logger.info("AGE===>"+results.getString(2));
    }
```

Eventhough I am getting records, the value is null. That means if the output is 2 rows, then the while condition executing and printing null. In SQL Developer it is working fine. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally found the answer [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/java.111/b31224/global.htm#CHDCHJJC). After including the orai18n.jar in class path, it is working fine.

Comment: Good to know, +1 for the reference link. but I followed the link - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3626061/how-to-call-oracle-stored-procedure-which-include-user-defined-type-in-java?lq=1 and it worked great