# How to convert Java List into an Oracle ARRAY to enter as a param in an Oracle Stored procedure?

Tags: java, arrays, oracle, stored-procedures, arraylist

I have the following `list` of Person Objects:

```
List<Person> persons;
```

The Person object is as follows:

```
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)
public class Person
{
    @XmlElement
    private int id;
    @XmlElement
    private String name;

    public Person(){

    }

}
```

A `Stored Procedure` I am invoking takes a list of Person Objects as an `Oracle ARRAY`.

How can I convert my list of Java Objects into an Oracle ARRAY in order to pass it into the Stored Procedure?

I have seen the `CallableStatement.setArray()` method, but I do not know how to convert my Java List into an Oracle ARRAY first.

Comment: Also duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3626061/how-to-call-oracle-stored-procedure-which-include-user-defined-type-in-java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create an sql Array using the method [createARRAY](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/appdev.112/e13995/oracle/jdbc/OracleConnection.html#createARRAY_java_lang_String__java_lang_Object_).

> Creates an ARRAY object with the given type name and elements.

Here a simple example

```
    String[] array = new String[]{"a", "b", "c"};
    oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver ora = new oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver();
    java.sql.Connection conn = ora.defaultConnection();
    oracle.jdbc.OracleConnection oraConn = (oracle.jdbc.OracleConnection) conn;
    java.sql.Array sqlArray = oraConn.createARRAY("typeName", array);
```

---

If you start from a `List` of `Object`

```
List<Object> list = ...
...
Object[] array = list.toArray();
oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver ora = new oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver();
java.sql.Connection conn = ora.defaultConnection();
oracle.jdbc.OracleConnection oraConn = (oracle.jdbc.OracleConnection) conn;
java.sql.Array sqlArray = oraConn.createARRAY("typeName", array);
```

---

Comment: Thanks, although will this work for an ArrayList of Objects ?

Comment: And also, what would the "typeName" be in my case, can you please show a complete example?

Comment: @java123999 I edited my answer to show how to use a List<Object>. The parameter type name is defined as: typeName - the name of the SQL type of the created object

Comment: Thanks for edit. So in my case what would the typeName be for a list of Person Objects?

Comment: Is the sql type. I don't know what name you used, probably Person?

Comment: ah ok, the SQL type that is stated in the Stored Procedure?