# Java code to handle Oracle function that takes two custom types as input parameters

Tags: java, oracle, callable-statement

I have a function in oracle which takes two custom types as input parameters.

```
set serveroutput on
DECLARE
 t_country_code  test_pkg_country.country_code_arr;
 t_country       test_pkg_country.country_tab_arr;

 v_id number := 3;
 v_str varchar2(1000);
BEGIN
 v_str := test_pkg_country.fnc_test_get_country(v_id, t_country_code, t_country);
 DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_str);
END;
```

The Parameters are of custom type.

```
TYPE country_code_arr IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(2) INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;
TYPE country_tab_arr IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(50) INDEX BY VARCHAR2(5);
```

In Java I am Handling like this

```
String sql = "{call test_pkg_country.fnc_test_get_country(?, ?, ?, ?)}";
CallableStatement cs = null;
cs = srcConn.prepareCall(sql);

            cs.setInt(1, OracleTypes.NUMBER);
            cs.setInt(2, OracleTypes.ARRAY);
            cs.setInt(3, OracleTypes.ARRAY);
            cs.registerOutParameter(4, OracleTypes.VARCHAR);
            cs.execute();
```

I am Getting an Exception. Please help me with the solution.

> java.sql.SQLException: ORA-06550: line 1, column 7: PLS-00306: wrong
>   number or types of arguments

Comment: What you want? Entire java code to access this function? Stackoverflow is not for homework issues.

Comment: I have posted the function above..I takes two custom data types an input parameters. I just need to know with which i have to register this callable statement

Comment: Java Code that i am using

String sql = "{call test_pkg_country.fnc_test_get_country(?, ?, ?, ?)}";
CallableStatement cs = null;
cs = srcConn.prepareCall(sql);
cs.setInt(1, OracleTypes.NUMBER);
cs.setInt(2, OracleTypes.ARRAY);
cs.setInt(3, OracleTypes.ARRAY);
cs.registerOutParameter(4, OracleTypes.VARCHAR);
cs.execute();

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to call oracle stored procedure which include user-defined type in java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3626061/how-to-call-oracle-stored-procedure-which-include-user-defined-type-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

```
TYPE country_code_arr IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(2) INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;
TYPE country_tab_arr IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(50) INDEX BY VARCHAR2(5);
```

You can't map these collections in JDBC directly. JDBC allows you to use only sql level objects. These two are associative array and exist only in scope of pl sql.

Jdbc only support Types indexed by number. For this types of assoativae array OracleCallableStatment has function setPlsqlIndexTable. 
For collction inedex by varcahr2 we have to create workaround.

```
try {

    Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);         
    CallableStatement cs = conn.prepareCall(
             "declare  " +
                     " TYPE country_code_arr IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(2) INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;  " +
                     " TYPE country_tab_arr IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(50) INDEX BY VARCHAR2(5);  " +
                     " TYPE workaround is table OF VARCHAR2(50)  INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;  " +
                     " countr_cod country_code_arr  := ?; " +
                     " country_list workaround := ? ; " +
                     "  contry_keys workaround  := ? ;  " +
                     " country_tab country_tab_arr;  " +
                     " res varchar2(4000); " +
                     " i BINARY_INTEGER; " +
                     " procedure make_my_array is  " +
                     "      i number; " +
                     " begin  " +
                     "       i := contry_keys.first(); " +
                     "       while i is not null loop      " +
                     "          country_tab(contry_keys(i)) := country_list(i); " +
                     "        i := contry_keys.next(i); " +
                     "      end loop; " +
                     " end;        " +
                     " function your_function(p1 country_code_arr, p2 country_tab_arr)  return varchar2  " +
                     "  is  " +
                     "   result_str varchar2(4000); " +
                     "     i BINARY_INTEGER; " +
                     "     key varchar2(10);" +
                     "  begin  " +
                     "     i := p1.first(); " +
                     "  while i is not null loop      " +
                     "    result_str :=result_str|| ',' || p1(i); " +
                     "    i := p1.next(i); " +
                     "  end loop; " +
                     "   " +
                     "    key := p2.first(); " +
                     "  while key is not null loop      " +
                     "        result_str :=result_str|| ',' ||key||';'|| p2(key); " +
                     "    key := p2.next(key); " +
                     "  end loop;  " +
                     "   " +
                     "  return result_str;  " +
                     "  end;  " +
                     "   " +
                     "begin " +
                     " null;" +
                     "  make_my_array; " +
                     " ? := your_function( countr_cod,country_tab); " + 
                     "end;  " );
     ((OracleCallableStatement)cs).setPlsqlIndexTable(1, new String[]{"AA","BN"},3, 2,  OracleTypes.VARCHAR, 2); //country_code_arr 
     ((OracleCallableStatement)cs).setPlsqlIndexTable(2, new String[]{"Country1","Country2"},3, 2,  OracleTypes.VARCHAR, 50); //country_tab_arr values 
     ((OracleCallableStatement)cs).setPlsqlIndexTable(3, new String[]{"k1","k2"},3, 2,  OracleTypes.VARCHAR, 2);  //country_tab_arr keys
     cs.registerOutParameter(4, OracleTypes.VARCHAR);

     cs.execute();
    System.err.println(cs.getString(4));
     cs.close();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: This is correct but is probably more a comment than an answer.Now, if you could just suggest an alternative.

Comment: How can i Handle this type of function in java. Please help @Arkadiusz Łukasiewicz

Comment: @VijayThompson: Please check the answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3626061/how-to-call-oracle-stored-procedure-which-include-user-defined-type-in-java)

Comment: @Vijay, I suggest that you change your function  to return a comma delimited String (varchar2) instead of a TABLE OF array. You only need to iterate through your table object and concatenate individual String values separated by a comma (e.g "val1, val2, val3 .....") It's trivial then to parse this string in Java. There are other approaches but this is very easy to implement.

Comment: @dsp_user. I cannot change the function in oracle....Only thing i can do is handle this funtion in java and return its test results.

Comment: The function Declaration is like this

create or replace package body test_pkg_country as

function fnc_test_get_country(p_id number, p_country_code in out country_code_arr, p_country in out country_tab_arr )
return varchar2

end test_pkg_country;

Comment: @Nitish I have looked at your solution.but mine is a little different...

Comment: @Vijaj, you can always write a new Pl/SQL wrapper function around the original function (I've updated my answer to include this). If you don't have access to your Oracle database, then possibly you can use some undocumented Oracle API (don't know if that'll work)

Answer (score 0):

Since you can't map a TABLE OF type (PlSql) directly in Java, you should modify your function to return a supported type (SQL type). Probably the easiest way is to rewrite your function declaration to

```
  CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE test_pkg_country.fnc_test_get_country(v_id IN NUMBER, t_country_code OUT VARCHAR2, t_country VARCHAR2)
     --DECLARATIONS AND BODY HERE
```

In your Pl/SQL function, map the values from the table to a string variable

```
t_country:= ''; --initialize with an empty string

FOR i..your_country_table.COUNT LOOP

t_country := t_country || your_country_table(i) || ',';

END LOOP;
t_country := substr(t_country, 0, length(t_country)-1);
```

Now, one additional thing, I've noticed that you're setting your first agument to a number value

```
 cs.setInt(1, OracleTypes.NUMBER);
```

but in your anonimous block the value returned from the function is a string, so you will need to check the correct types.

```
v_str := test_pkg_country.fnc_test_get_country(v_id, t_country_code, t_country);
```

One final thing, if you can't change the original function, you will need to write a wrapper Pl/Sql function (basically this function will call the original function but return different/supported types).

Answer (score 0):

Ok I got the answer. The way I executed the function in oracle, that same plsql I stored in an string variable and executed using normal callable statement and got the result. Thanks for the help guys.

```
String sql = "set serveroutput on
DECLARE
 t_country_code  test_pkg_country.country_code_arr;
 t_country       test_pkg_country.country_tab_arr;

 v_id number := 3;
BEGIN
 ? := test_pkg_country.fnc_test_get_country(v_id, t_country_code, t_country);
 DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_str);
END;"

cs = con.prepareCall(sql);
ocs.registerOutParameter(1, Types.VARCHAR);
cs.execute();
System.out.println(cs.getString(1));
```

will work fine for these kinds of problems