# Calling a stored procedure with an array as parameter

Tags: java, oracle, stored-procedures, spring-data

Using Java and Spring Data, I need to call the following stored procedure from an Oracle database:

```
TYPE R_ID_INSC_TYPE IS RECORD(id_insc  INSC_REGISTRE.ID%TYPE);
TYPE T_ID_INSC IS TABLE OF R_ID_INSC_TYPE INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;

PROCEDURE CHARGER_RECHERCHE
(
    P_NO_DEMANDE    IN NUMBER,
    P_SEQ_DEM       IN NUMBER,
    P_ETAPE_RECH    IN VARCHAR2,
    P_ID_INSC_TAB   IN T_ID_INSC
);
```

What seems to be causing me trouble is the last parameter in this stored procedure, which is meant to be a list of ids. Here's how I'm calling it in Java:

```
public void call(final Integer numeroDemande,
                 final Integer numeroSequenceDemande,
                 final EtapeRecherche etapeRecherche,
                 final Integer[] ids) {

    new SimpleJdbcCall(this.jdbcTemplate)
            .withSchemaName(this.schemaName)
            .withProcedureName(this.procedureName)
            .declareParameters(
                    new SqlParameter("P_NO_DEMANDE", Types.INTEGER),
                    new SqlParameter("P_SEQ_DEM", Types.INTEGER),
                    new SqlParameter("P_ETAPE_RECH", Types.VARCHAR),
                    new SqlParameter("P_ID_INSC_TAB", Types.ARRAY))
            .execute(numeroDemande, numeroSequenceDemande, etapeRecherche.getValue(), ids);
}
```

Which throws the following error:

```
org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: CallableStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [{call PLATEFORME.CHARGER_RECHERCHE()}];
nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'CHARGER_RECHERCHE'
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
```

The person responsible for the implementation of the stored procedure also gave us the following usage example:

```
declare

P_ID_INSC_TAB  PLATEFORME.T_ID_INSC;
P_NO_DEMANDE   NUMBER:=317225;
P_SEQ_DEM NUMBER:=1;
P_ETAPE_RECH VARCHAR2(2):='AI';

begin


P_ID_INSC_TAB(1).id_insc:=1258773;
P_ID_INSC_TAB(2).id_insc:=1258774;
P_ID_INSC_TAB(3).id_insc:=1258775;

PLATEFORME.CHARGER_RECHERCHE(P_NO_DEMANDE,P_SEQ_DEM,P_ETAPE_RECH,P_ID_INSC_TAB);

end;
```

The person responsible for the implementation of the stored procedure also offered to change the definition to this one, if it can make it any easier:

```
TYPE T_ID_INSC IS TABLE OF NUMBER(9) INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;

PROCEDURE CHARGER_RECHERCHE
(
    P_NO_DEMANDE    IN NUMBER,
    P_SEQ_DEM       IN NUMBER,
    P_ETAPE_RECH    IN VARCHAR2,
    P_ID_INSC_TAB   IN T_ID_INSC
);
```

What would I need to do in order to successfully call this stored procedure?

Thanks.

Comment: See if this similar question helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3626061/how-to-call-oracle-stored-procedure-which-include-user-defined-type-in-java

Answer (score 1):

T_ID_INSC is an Oracle type.
ids cannot be a java Integer array.
Try this (conn is the oracle connection):

```
import java.sql.*;
import oracle.jdbc.*;
import oracle.sql.*;

ArrayDescriptor arrDesc = ArrayDescriptor.createDescriptor("T_ID_INSC", conn);
Integer[] data = {1258773, 1258774, 1258775};
Array ids = new ARRAY(arrDesc, conn, data);
```

or else try:

```
import java.sql.*;
import oracle.jdbc.*;
import oracle.sql.*;

Integer[] data = {1258773, 1258774, 1258775};
Array ids = ((OracleConnection)conn).createOracleArray("T_ID_INSC", data);
```

Comment: ArrayDescriptor is deprecated now.

Answer (score 0):

You can put the Ids is a loop and call the the stored procedure.
like below:

```
for (int i=0;i<arr.size();i++) 
{
int id=arr[i];
//call stored procedure here, passing id
}
```